# How do I pass the result from a command to another command's option in a single npm run script?

Tags: json, node.js

I'm not sure whether this is possible in a single line, but I want to run yaml2json and pass the result json to jade -O option in CLI.

I know if I write the json file and specify the output file path in `-O` option, it works.  But I would rather not write some temporary file if this can be done without it.

So This works

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "jade": "yaml2json src/data/site.yaml > temp.json && jade src/jade/pages --out dist -O temp.json",
  }
}
```

However this doesn't.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "jade": "jade src/jade/pages --out dist -O yaml2json src/data/site.yaml"
  }
}
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using backticks (the grave)?

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "jade": "jade src/jade/pages --out dist -O \"`yaml2json src/data/site.yaml`\""
  }
}
```

Or you could remove the temporary file afterwards if it is lingering (Linux/OSX only):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "jade": "yaml2json src/data/site.yaml > temp.json && jade src/jade/pages --out dist -O temp.json && rm temp.json",
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you shenan.  Back-tick solved it!  I had to escape the argument so it was like this: `"jade": "jade src/jade/pages --out dist -O \"`yaml2json src/data/site.yaml`\""`

Comment: @Gen your comment example is formatted odd (probably because it uses backticks). I've updated my answer to what I suspect you meant. Could you verify that I have applied the escaped quotes correctly, so that others are helped by the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, updated answer works perfect!  Thanks for the update.